# How can I get, the ListViewControl on GridViewColumnHeader Click Event

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, sender

I have 7 different ListViews.

There is a Sortmethod called `SortClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)` -
when clicking on a GridViewColumnHeader, it raises the SortClick Event.

But in this method I must tell, which ListView should be Sorted, b.e

```
listview2.SortNow();
```

Now my Question is, how can I get the Control (ListView) from the GridViewColumnHeader (`sender`) or maybe the `e`, is that even possible?

How the ListView XAML looks like:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding MissingTables}" Name="missingTablesListView" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0" MinHeight="540" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
                    <ListView.Background>
                        <ImageBrush />
                    </ListView.Background>
                    <ListView.View>
                        <GridView>
                            <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding TableName}" Width="Auto">
                                <GridViewColumnHeader Click="SortClick" Content="TableName" Tag="TableName" ToolTip="Sortieren" />
                            </GridViewColumn>   
                            <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Beschreibung}" Width="Auto">
                                <GridViewColumnHeader Click="SortClick" Content="Description" Tag="Beschreibung" ToolTip="Sortieren" />
                            </GridViewColumn>
                        </GridView>
                    </ListView.View>
                </ListView>
```

Here is the SortClick Code:

```
        /// <summary>
        /// Sortiert (Ascending/Descending)
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender">sender</param>
        /// <param name="e">e</param>
        private void SortClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {       
            //ListView listView = sender as ListView;

            GridViewColumnHeader column = sender as GridViewColumnHeader;
            String field = column.Tag as String;

            if (currentSortColumn != null)
            {
                AdornerLayer.GetAdornerLayer(currentSortColumn).Remove(sorter);
                listView.Items.SortDescriptions.Clear();
            }

            ListSortDirection newDir = ListSortDirection.Ascending;
            if (currentSortColumn == column && sorter.Direction == newDir)
            {
                newDir = ListSortDirection.Descending;
            }

            currentSortColumn = column;
            sorter = new Sorter(currentSortColumn, newDir);
            AdornerLayer.GetAdornerLayer(currentSortColumn).Add(sorter);
            listView.Items.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription(field, newDir));
        }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what you mean when you say SortClick Event, but i guess you mean the `GridViewColumnHeader.Click` event with your `SortClick` handler attached.

If you add the `GridViewColumnHeader.Click` to the ListViews like this:

```
<ListView GridViewColumnHeader.Click="SortClick">
```

you will get the `ListView` control in the `sender` argument of your event handler, and the `GridViewColumnHeader` in `e.OriginalSource`.

EDIT for clarity. In your `SortClick` handler, you'll access the control like this:

```
ListView listView = sender as ListView;
GridViewColumnHeader header = e.OriginalSource as GridViewColumnHeader;
```

Comment: yes, but how I get the ListView control from the sender argument?

Comment: By `ListView listView = sender as ListView;`.

Comment: Can you please post the XAML of (one of) your ListViews, where you attach the click handler?

Comment: Add the `SortClick` handler to the `ListView` (as shown in my answer), not to the `GridViewColumnHeader`.

Comment: yes, now the listView isn't null, but now I cannot use `sender as GridViewColumnHeader` , I posted my code

Comment: Read my answer, you'll get the `GridViewColumnHeader` from `e.OriginalSource`.

Comment: Please note that GridViewColumnHeader.Click is effectively ButtonBase.Click. That is, any button based controls in the list view will trigger this event, e.g. by clicking on a a toggle button or checkbox.

Answer (score 2):

I would go with Clemens's solution, but if it's not an option for you, you can also walk up the visual tree to find the ListView:

```
    static T FindAncestor<T>(DependencyObject obj) where T : DependencyObject
    {
        var tmp = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(obj);
        while (tmp != null && !(tmp is T))
        {
            tmp = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(tmp);
        }
        return (T)tmp;
    }

    ...

    var listView = FindAncestor<ListView>(columnHeader);
```

Comment: thx for your solution, but thats to complicated for me :) + 1 for doing this anyway